# What kind of geo information is stored in a GeoTIFF

Tags: geotiff-tiff

When given a geotiff, what kind of information is normally stored in it as part of the geo information?

Is it the position of the 4 corners?
Is it the position of each pixel?
Is it a mesh of geo points?

(Latest OpenCV include gdal support and the option to Open geotiff files and I was wondering what kind of information i will be able to find in it? as I have a goal of writing a small program that can tile a DEM model up in XYZ tiles using OpenCV)

Comment: I would start by reading the spec http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/spec/contents.html

Comment: Been reading the spec and I still are not really sure if its juts doing a homography/perspective warp of image or its interpolating between points and doing a rubber sheet technique.

Comment: I may be wrong but I do not believe that geotiff cares about that. For example if gereferencing is defined by ground control points programs like gdalwarp can do the real warping with different algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

"Georeferencing from GeoTIFF is supported in the form of one tiepoint and pixel size, a transformation matrix, or a list of GCPs."

http://gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html

The 6 value transform will be the usual way for most simple cases, the other crucial part is the CRS. Still, TIFF and GeoTIFF are quite complex containers so this is a big simplification.

This page describes the transform as applied in tfw, though of course GeoTIFF does this internally *not* via auxilliary file:

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file